# How to push new key with integer value in array PHP

Tags: php

Hello im trying to do this but print or vap_dump show nothing as value. it works with string but not with integer

```
$a=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green");
array_push($a['new'],1);
print_r($a);
```

Help, thanks

Comment: You could always have look at the examples that go with almost all pages in the [PHP MANUAL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) and which are almost always great at answering simple questions about function usage

Comment: Hint: don't use array_push for this

Comment: simply use the line `$a["new"] = 1;` (instead of `array_push($a['new'],1);` )

Comment: `it works with string but not with integer`...not true: https://3v4l.org/HDppU . Unless you meant something else? You should always provide _code_ to describe this sort of thing.

Comment: Read https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php - specifically the section titled "Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax ".

Answer (score 1):

Check docs for array_push.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

First argument is the array you want to push to.

In your example you are trying to add an element to **$a['new']**, but **$a['new']** is not an array.

So do this instead.

```
$a=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green");
array_push($a,1);
print_r($a);
```

Edit:
As ADyson mentioned, if your intent is to add a value with a specific key, you would simply do:

```
$a['new'] = 1;
```

Comment: I would assume OP is trying to create a key called "new". Your example doesn't do that.

Comment: Well assume all you want, but if you want to add a key called new, you wouldn't use array_push, you would do simply $a['new'] = 1;

Comment: I know that - see my comments above. Maybe add it to your answer in case the OP needs to know and somehow can't find the PHP manual. You're assuming one thing, I'm assuming another. Both examples would cover off any ambiguity.